# UML sequence diagram - naming / system assumption

Tags: uml, sequence, system, diagram, scenarios

I want to make a sequence diagram of below scenario

1. User clicks 'Pay' button
2. X asks for card payment details.
3. Use enters card number, expiry date ect
   (...)
4. X sends a request to the bank for payment authorization.

How can I name the object X, other than the system, because a system is in fact a whole in which a sequence diagram happens?

For school purposes, is it correct to assume in the scenario that the system I am creating asks for card details (i.e. stores them) and sends a request to the bank for authorization?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. What you call system is actually an instance of a certain class dealing with the authorization. If there were only one class to handle it all you probably would not need any (UML) design at all. The X would probably be an instance of `Authorization`.